# Critical Problem with Sharepoint Timer Job Properties

Tags: sharepoint, timer, jobs

Some minutes ago I tried to create a time job

A added some properties like

this.Properties.Add("fileName", fileName);
this.Properties.Add("username", new NetworkCredential("username", "passworD");

After updating the job a get a critical error in the Timer Job list of the Central Administration occured.

*The platform does not know how to deserialize an object of type System.Net.NetworkCredential. The platform can deserialize primitive types such as strings, integers, and GUIDs; other SPPersistedObjects or SPAutoserializingObjects; or collections of any of the above. Consider redesigning your objects to store values in one of these supported formats, or contact your software vendor for support.*

Now Im unabled to delete or retract the job with SPJobdefinition's Delete() method or other classes within the SPObject model.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got it.
I deleted the corresponding object in the SharepointConfigDatabase.dbo.Objects table